# PCI-E 2.0 x8 SAS/SATA RAID controllers recommendations for Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid, ubuntu-10.04

What RAID controllers are there that meet the following?

- Works out of the box with good performance with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
- PCI-E 2.0 x4 or x8
- Support for 8 or more SATA/SAS 6Gb/s drives
- Enough internal bandwidth to support full speed of all drives simultaneously
- Able to expose all the drives as JBOD so that Linux software raid can be used

Answer (score 1):

If you want JBOD, why do you search for the raid card? You may get much cheaper HBA i.e. [LSI SAS3081E-R](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/host_bus_adapters/sas_hbas/lsisas3081er/).

Comment: An HBA would be fine as well. Too bad that one you linked to does not do 6BG/s per port or PCI-E 2.0.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no many SATA3 controllers in the market yet. A disk drives just don't require such speed, unless you have some expensive SSDs or DDR drives. 3Gbit per lane supports up to 375 megabytes/second - I even can't say what SSD model can fully support it.